# Blink the time like a real digital clock

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am displaying the current time like this way :

```
$('#mydiv').html(
   new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', 
     { hour12: false, hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' }));
```

and it is displayed for example like this :

16:13

How is it possible to make the two dots blink every one second like a real digital clock?

Answer (score 6):

I fully agree with mplungjan, that there are better questions to ask, however, it also seemed fun todo :)

The blinking part, you could actually do with CSS, no need for javascript tricks (see the second example)

```js
var clockEl = document.querySelector('#clock');

function getTime() {
  return new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', 
     { hour12: false, hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' }).toString();
}

function setTime() {
  var time = getTime();
  // check if the colon is there
  if (clockEl.innerText.split(':').length === 1) {
    // if it's not, set the actual time
    clockEl.innerText = time;
  } else {
    // if it is, remove the colon
    clockEl.innerText = time.split(':').join(' ');
  }
}

setInterval( setTime , 1000);
setTime();
```

```css
#clock { font-family: 'Courier new' }
```

```html
<div id="clock"></div>
```

```js
var oldTime;

function setTime() {
  var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', 
     { hour12: false, hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' });
  if (oldTime === time) {
    return;
  }
  oldTime = time;
  time = time.split(':');
  document.querySelector('#hours').innerText = time[0];
  document.querySelector('#minutes').innerText = time[1];
}

setInterval( setTime, 1000);
setTime();
```

```css
.separator {
  animation: blinker 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {  
  50% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <span id="hours"></span>
  <span class="separator">:</span>
  <span id="minutes"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first one moves and the second one is faster than once a second ;)

Comment: @mplungjan Sure it does, he didn't really specify that :) I really don't care, if I would, I would use like courier new or something :)

Comment: But when it blinks too fast it does not look realistic :P

Comment: @mplungjan Only for you, I made it blink slower and it no longer moves in the first example ^_^;;

Comment: Not sure why you were voted down... perhaps someone really do not want us to answer poor questions

Comment: When the colon starts blinking, the numbers move a bit. How to avoid that?

Comment: @BLS ensure that you have a fixed width font, or make sure that the blocks are always the same size

Comment: @Icepickle I am using "montserrat" as my font, and I cant seem to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

I was intrigued so I could not help answering.

```js
var toggle = true;
setInterval(function() {
  var d = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false, hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' });
  var parts = d.split(":");
  $('#hours').text(parts[0]);
  $('#minutes').text(parts[1]);
  $("#colon").css({ visibility: toggle?"visible":"hidden"});
  toggle=!toggle;
},1000);
```

```css
#colon { visibility:hidden }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span id="hours"></span><span id="colon">:</span><span id="minutes"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, you even updated it to an improved version before I could write a comment on the moving values after changing the colon xD.

Comment: :) Yeah, I did not like that either

Comment: I was thinking you could blink the colon with CSS, although you'd still need the interval to update the time, so it's pretty redundant: https://jsfiddle.net/uw4et1a0/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Nice! j08691 did something similar in his deleted answer

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Once we're using CSS animations anyway, we can let the animation clock take over the heavy lifting from `setInterval` for the time changes, too: https://jsfiddle.net/pnichols04/19sz7k7e/

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a moving issue with @mplungjan

Replace

```
clockEl.innerText = time.split(':').join(' ');
```

with

```
clockEl.innerText = time.split(':').join("\u2009");
```

to solve the moving issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I played along with the other JavaScript answers, but as I am running quite a lot on the website this meant the clock ticking was slowed by everything else running.

I realized instead there is a trivial CSS solution.

```
function getTime() {
  return new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Europe/London', hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit' });
}
```

Then rendering

```
<h4>
  {time[0]}
  <span className="timeSep">:</span>
  {time[1]}
</h4>
```

And adding the CSS

```
.timeSep{
  animation: blink 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49%  { opacity: 0; }
  50%  { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, still a bit of fun, here's a slightly more verbose es6 example

```js
function blinkingTime() {
  const timeString = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
    hour12: false,
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric'
  });
  const [hours, mins, seconds] = timeString.split(':');
  const centreChar = seconds % 2 === 0 ? ':' : ' ';
  return `${hours}${centreChar}${mins}`;
}

function updateTime() {
  console.log(blinkingTime());
  setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);
}

updateTime();
```

Comment: That will not update on a page and the seconds will move a millimeter since a space is smaller than a colon. You need to use something the same width as a space

Comment: Hah, I suppose so. Could do a nearly pure CSS example too using a white square.But I guess im more about the logic of the thing :)

Comment: Someone does not like we answer poor questions :/